# Reading Data stored via Autoid from Firebase Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to access the contents of data that is stored via childByAutoID in firebase using swift. Currently I am very new to this and am just printing out the value of snapshot.value. I want to be able to access both key value pairs stored in each ID.

Here is my current code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        ref.child("Phrases").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
            snapshot in

            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

            print(value)

        })



    }
```

This is outputting:

```
Optional({
    "-KkNM7b33sqba0XF-Nob" =     {
        phrase = "Bonjour!";
        translation = "Hello!";
    };
})
```

I am want to be able to access value["phrase"] and translation as well.

How do I do this?

EDIT: Here is a photo of the db:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I usually do this is by:

```
ref.child("Phrases").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

 let value = snapshot.value as! [String:Any]
 let name = value["phrase"] as? String ?? ""
})
```

Alternatively you could unwrap it first

```
ref.child("Phrases").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

  if let value = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {
    let name = value["phrase"] as? String ?? ""
  }
})
```

Comment: This is getting closer, now I am getting nil when printing it out. Even though I know there is something in db. Above is the photo of my db

Comment: This is because your snapshot contains snapshot children. You need to enumerate over them and then do as above.

Comment: The above could should work if you used .childAdded instead of .value. But then that might not suit your usecase.

Comment: That worked... Still don't know how but I am going to now look into the different method options for fetching data. Thanks for the help!